# Java Spring: How to specify resource path's correctly in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring

I am just working on a Spring project where the former developer used some full pathes for resource access in *`application.properties`* like:

```
java.resource=/full/path/src/main/resources/somefile
webapp.resource=/full/path/src/main/webapp/resources/somefile
```

I think it's no good practice to link into the sources folder, right?

As I can see files from *`src/main/resources/`* are extracted into Tomcat's *`webapps/projekt-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes`* directory and files from *`src/main/webapp/resources/`* are extracted into *`webapps/projekt-1.0.0/resources`*.

How to do this the right way so that I don't need separate *`.properties`* Files for *development/staging* etc?

Comment: You can have different properties per environment. If you are using Spring Boot, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Answer (score 0):

From your directory structure may I assume you're using Maven? If that true, then your statements was correct. Maven structure directory automatically scan `src/main/resources` path as the build path, so you only need to put your properties file in there and call the file on your `applicationContext.xml`.

```
<!-- read value from .properties file -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:<your_file_name>.properties"/>
```